# Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:3000/sw-import.js/resources

Tags: node.js, swagger, loopbackjs, strongloop, swagger-ui

I am new to node and swagger and am going through loopback.io examples to try and build an API.

I have node, strongloop installed on my machine. I created a new loopback application and set up a quick 'user' model and tried to run swagger explorer to see if I can view the APIs. However, I get the following error when I run localhost:3000/explorer/

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured it after banging my head against the table for two hours.

Chrome was storing an incorrect swagger token across sessions in local storage. Had to delete the token and everything's good.